# Visual studio writes 4 characters for each pressed key in cshtml files

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, github-copilot

I'm working with a .cshtml file in visual studio, the first seconds after I open the file everything seems normal, but after I write some letters Visual Studio starts writing 4 characters for each pressed key...
[image: Example of output when error occurs]

I'm working with Visual Studio 2022 V17.2.5 (Community edition), ASP.NET Framework V4.6.1 and using Razor pages. Assuming its a bug i'm reporting it as one to Microsoft ¿Has anyone run with the same problem and a solution to work around it?

This is the entire .cshtml file:

```
@model CataRefacciones
@using SCORE.Helpers
@using SCORE.Models
@using X.PagedList

@{
    string idTipos = "ListaTipos";
    var listaTipos = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ListaDeTipos;
    string idCodigos = "ListaCodigos";
    var listaCodigoSAT = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ListaDeCodigos;
    string idMarcas = "ListaMarcas";
    var listaMarcas = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)SCOREEntitiesHelper.ListaMarcasRefacciones();
    var listaUniAlmacenaje = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ListaUniAlmacenaje;
    string CodigoSAT = Model.CODSAT.ToString();
    bool esVistaCreacion = ViewBag.AccionStd == CataAcciones.AccionesStd.Agregar;

    // Necesitamos guardar la lista de modelos, guardaremos un string con los ids separados por coma...
    ViewBag.nameListaModRef = Html.FieldName(model => model.ListaIdsModelos);
}

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ListaIdsModelos)

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IDREFACCION)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IDPROVEEDOR) @*Identifica al proveedor por defecto*@
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IDPRESENTACIONDEFECTO) @*Identifica a la presentación por defecto*@

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <h6>General</h6>
        @{
            object additionalViewData = new
            {
                htmlAttributes =
                         new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = string.Format("ValidarCodigo(this, {0})", Model.IDREFACCION) }
            };
        }
        <div class="row">
            @Html.EtiquetaYControl(model => model.CODIGO, "col-lg-2 coooollll----mmmmdddd----1111", additionalViewData)
            @Html.EtiquetaYControl(model => model.TIPOPRODUCTO, "col-lg-2", additionalViewData)
            @Html.EtiquetaYTextArea(model => model.DESCRIPCION, "col-lg-5")
            @Html.EtiquetaYControl(model => model.ACTIVO, "col-md-1 col-xs-4")
            @Html.EtiquetaYControl(model => model.ORIGINAL, "col-md-1 col-xs-4")
            @Html.EtiquetaYControl(model => model.AccesorioBool, "col-md-1 col-xs-4")
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            @Html.EtiquetaYLista(model => model.TIPOACCESORIO, listaTipos, "col-md-2",
                 new { @class = "form-control", @id = idTipos })
            @Html.EtiquetaYLista(model => model.IDUNIDADALMACENAJE, listaUniAlmacenaje, "col-md-2",
                 new { @onchange = "", @class = "form-control combobox captura-estricta" }, "Unidad de control de inventario para esta refacción")
            @Html.EtiquetaYLista(model => model.MarcaSinEspacios, listaMarcas, "col-md-2",
                 new { @class = "form-control combobox ancho-sin-limite", @id = idMarcas })
            @Html.EtiquetaYLista(model => model.CodSatString, listaCodigoSAT, "col-md-2",
                 new
                 {
                     // Marcamos el campo como requerido en este punto. No lo hacemos en el modelo de refacción
                     // ya que esto generaría errores durante procesos de guardado automáticos (como lo es
                     // la configuración de presentaciones y unidad de almacenaje desde pantalla de detalles)
                     @class = "form-control combobox ancho-sin-limite",
                     @id = idCodigos,
                     @onchange = "javascript:onChangeCodSAT(g_refaccion)"
                 }, null, "requerido")
            @Html.EtiquetaYTextArea(model => model.DESCODSAT, "col-md-4")
        </div>
        <br />
        @* Pills de selección de tabs. *@
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="presentation">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#sucursales" data-toggle="tab">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" title="Sucursales" rel="tooltip"></span>
                    <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">Sucursales</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#proveedores" data-toggle="tab">
                    <img src="~/images/proveedores.png" height="20" title="Proveedores" rel="tooltip" />
                    <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">Proveedores</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a onclick="javascript:ClickTabModelos();" href="#modelos" data-toggle="tab">
                    <img src="~/images/modelos.png" height="20" title="Modelos" rel="tooltip" />
                    <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">Modelos</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#similares" data-toggle="tab">
                    <img src="~/images/similares.png" height="20" title="Similares" rel="tooltip" />
                    <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">Similares</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#kardex" onclick="g_refaccion.actualizarTablaKdx()" data-toggle="tab">
                    <img src="~/images/kardex.png" height="20" title="Kárdex" rel="tooltip" />
                    <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">Kárdex</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <br />
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="sucursales" class="tab-pane active">
                @Html.Partial("Edicion/EditSeccionSucursales")
            </div>
            <div id="proveedores" class="tab-pane">
                @* Proveedores *@
                <div id="relacion_prov_ref">
                    @Html.Partial("RefaccionProveedor", Model.rlnProveedores_Refacciones.OrderBy(r => r.CataProveedores.RAZONSOCIAL).ToPagedList(1, 10))
                </div>

                @*Sección de modales*@
                @Html.Partial("RefaccionProveedorModalesYRegistros")
            </div>
            <div id="modelos" class="tab-pane">
                @* Modelos *@
                @Html.Partial("RefaccionModelo", Model.ParaModRefacciones.ToPagedList(1, 100))

                @if (!esVistaCreacion)
                {
                    <div id="modelos_en_OT">
                        @*Para los modelos en ordenes de trabaja cargaremos un mensaje de espera, la sección cargará una vez renderizada la pantalla*@
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="alert alert-info">
                                <h5>Cargando modelos en ordenes de trabajo...</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <div id="similares" class="tab-pane">
                @Html.Partial("Edicion/EditRefaccionesSimilares", Model)
            </div>
            <div id="kardex" class="tab-pane">
                @Html.Partial("KardexRefaccionSucursal", Model)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: How long does this behavior last? Once you get past the first few seconds of normal and it starts doing this does it last forever? Is it anywhere in the file or only in strings like you show? Have you tried disabling any extensions you have installed?

Comment: It last forever, and just found out that outside Razor expressions the words only repeat twice... Will try disabling some extensions

Comment: It really sounds like you have some sort of extension that is acting up. I can’t imagine what kind of extension would need to insert keystrokes the user just executed, but if it did and suddenly it wasn’t handling the event properly I would expect this kind of behavior. Check your installed extensions and disable any that aren’t from Microsoft specifically and edit your question with the results.

Comment: You should move the solution you put in your edit into an answer and then accept it. It's better for you to answer your own question because it shows up as having an answer when people search the site. And it shows up on your profile as contributing an answer to the community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried disabling some extensions as @Logarr suggested and found out the GitHub Copilot extension was causing the issue, then I disabled the 'Enable For HTMLProjection' option on the copilot quick menu and the abnormal behaviour stopped occurring...

[image: Disabling 'Enable for htmlprojection' option]

Still don't know why the issue only happened in certain cshtml files, hope this helps someone facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, except I was only getting 2 characters, not 4.

It was only affecting .cshtml files in VS2023.

I had the 'Use Legacy Razor editor for ASP.NET' selected. This had not been a problem until it decided to go haywire halfway through a coding session.

Change it to False and restart VS.

[image]

Comment: I had also the duplicate keys annoying behavior. Checked this and it was False. Changed to True, and restarted VS. Continued happening. Came here again and returned it back to false and restarted one more time. It is still happening... :(

Comment: @Kid: I think I solved the keystrokes duplication problem, when I was not even trying to fix it. I can't know if it was really the solution, but I don't want to get back to the old situation. It seems if I go to WinMerge change the file encoding from "01252 - Western European (Windows)" to "65001 - Unicode (UTF-8)", with BOM, problem becomes solved. After this change, I had to fix some French spelling where there were accents.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repro this and it doesn't seem like Copilot causes this issue anymore. Please try again with the latest version of the extension on your cshtml file!